# What is the automorphism group of the field $\mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z}(t)$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Here, $t$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z}$. How big is this group? What are its elements? Is for example the map $t \to -t$ an automorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k$ is a field, then the automorphism group of $k(t)$ as an extension of $k$ is the [projective general linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group) $\text{PGL}_2(k)$. Its elements are [fractional linear transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation)

$$t \mapsto \frac{at + b}{ct + d}, a, b, c, d \in k, ad - bc \neq 0.$$

This is a nice exercise. To start, first show that a map $k(t) \to k(t)$ of extensions of $k$ is determined by where it sends $t$, then figure out what the image of $t$ has to be in order for an inverse to exist. (In your example, $t \mapsto -t$ is clearly an automorphism because it is its own inverse.)

Comment: Figuring out the size of this group over a finite field is also a nice exercise. To start, figure out the size of $\text{GL}_2(k)$ (there are various ways to do this), then figure out the size of the kernel of the projection $\text{GL}_2(k) \to \text{PGL}_2(k)$.

Comment: What areas of mathematics studies infinite fields of characteristic p?

Comment: Number theory / arithmetic geometry / algebraic geometry. Somewhere around there.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is an automorphism of a field and $t$ a member of the field, then $\varphi(t^2)$ should be the same as $(\varphi(t))^2$.  This would appear to mean $\dfrac{at^2+b}{ct^2+d}=\left(\dfrac{at+b}{ct+d}\right)^2$.  Understood in the usual way, this is false.  How, then, is this to be understood? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael: as you say, $\varphi(t^2)$ is $\varphi(t)^2$. It is not given by plugging $t^2$ into the formula I gave above. The formula above says "$t \mapsto$" for a reason.